# Banned user cant be found in BansCollection using fetchBans()

Tags: discord, discord.js

ok so i made sure to check ids,
the user im trying to unban is banned.
the id is correct
i tried to console log what userBanned returns and it is undefined
like how?

```
    const text = args.join(` `)
const bansCollection = await message.guild.fetchBans()
const userBanned = bansCollection.find(user => user.id == text)
if (!isNaN(text)) {
    if (userBanned) {
       await message.guild.members.unban(text)
       message.channel.send(`<@${text}> has been unbanned`)
    } else { message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle(`**That user is not Banned!**`)) }

} else { message.channel.send(`You Need the user's ID!`) }
```

`console.log(text , bansCollection, userBanned)}`

Answer (score 0):

I would fetch the audit logs nd filter them.
Example:

```js
message.guild.fetchAuditLogs()
    .then(logs => {
        let ban = logs.entries.filter(e => e.action === 'MEMBER_BAN_ADD') //get all the bans
        ban = ban.filter(e => e.target.id === text) //filter the bans from the user
        
        if (!message.guild.members.cache.get(text)) return message.channel.send(`This user is not in this server.`);
        if (userBanned) {
            await message.guild.members.unban(text)
            message.channel.send(`<@${text}> has been unbanned`);
        } else {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
            embed.setTitle(`**That user is not Banned!**`);
            message.channel.send(embed);
        }
    });
```